# JPanel not responding to keylistener

Tags: keylistener

I tried to make a JPanel that would display how many times you press each navigation key, but it is only displaying 4 zeros.

//In the keyPressed() method, I put the following code that handles key presses accordingly:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    left++;             
    else if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    right++;            
    else if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    up++;               
    else if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    down++;
}
```

//the paint method to paint the counts over JPanel

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString ( Integer.toString(left),   100, 100 );
    g.drawString ( Integer.toString(right),  200, 100 );
    g.drawString ( Integer.toString(up),     100, 200 );
    g.drawString ( Integer.toString(down),   200, 200 );    
}
```

Comment: Does the execution of the program enter the `keyPressed` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Call `repaint();` in `keyPressed()` method in the end.
- Call `count_keys.setFocusable(true);` in `main` method just below its creation

Because `JPanel` is not focus able hence `KeyListener` is not working.

Comment: And the moment another component gains focus, the `KeyListener` will stop responding...

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the wonderful world of `KeyListener`s.

`KeyListener`s by design, can only respond to key events when the component they are registered to is focusable AND has focus.

This generally makes them a poor choice in a gaming environment, where you might have a number of components that can steal focus from you main game component.

Instead, you should be using [Key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)