# Issue with adding a JPanel onto another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am making a game and I have it so when I press a button on a menu I made, it loads the game. Both the game and the menu are `JPanel`s. The problem is when I click the button it loads the JPanel but the keyboard input doesn't work. Why might this be happening?
Here is the my code:

```
public class Menu extends JPanel  {
    static boolean load = false;
    JButton play = new JButton("play");
    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();

    public Menu(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(play);


        setVisible(true);  
        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Runner.panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(570,700));
                    add(Runner.panel,0,0);
                    //repaint();
                    validate();
            }
       });
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g){
       super.paint(g);
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
       draw(g2d);

   }

   public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){

       g2d.drawImage(getBulletImage(),0,0,null);

   }



   // gets the image file for the player class
   public Image getBulletImage(){
       ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("Menu.png");
       return ic.getImage();
   }

}
```

When the button is clicked in, it adds a `JPanel` on top of the current `JPanel`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

Read this post [JPanel not responding to keylistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547485/jpanel-not-responding-to-keylistener/22547559#22547559) that is asked in the same context.

---

#### Some Points:

- Override `paintComponent()` method of `JPanel` instead of overriding `paint()` method.

  Sample code:

  ```
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
      // your custom painting
  }
  ```
- Override [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) method instead of `setPreferredSize()` method. Don't set the size of the component and just hand over it to Layout Manager to set the size and position of the components that why it's made for.

  Sample code:

  ```
  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
      return new Dimension(100,50);
  }
  ```

  Read more [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)
- Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

  Read more

  - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
  - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding play.setFocusable(true); and play.requestFocus(); after you have created the new JPanel. This should put the focus in the new panel and allow keyboard input

Comment: +1 for making the panel focusable. -1 for suggesting requestFocus(). Don't use requestFocus(). The proper method to use is `requestFocusInWindow()`